# Mapear sub propriedade

Tags: c#, automapper

Tenho três classes

```
public class Ligacao
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public string ArquivoJson { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataLigacao { get; set; }
    public int CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
}

public class LigacaoGetResponse
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataLigacao { get; set; }
    public LigacaoGet Ligacao { get; set; }
}

public class LigacaoGet
{
    public int Fila { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public string Ordem { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public LigacaoGetCamposAdicionais[] CamposAdicionais { get; set; }
}
```

A classe "Ligacao" é a minha fonte de dados. As classes "LigacaoGetResponse" e "LigacaoGet" receberão os dados. Configurei o mapeamento dessa forma:

```
Mapper
    .CreateMap<Entities.Ligacao.Ligacao, LigacaoGetResponse>()
    .ForMember(src => src.Ligacao, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LigacaoGet>(dest.ArquivoJson)));

Mapper
    .CreateMap<Entities.Ligacao.Ligacao, LigacaoGet>()
    .ForMember(src => src.RequestId, opt => opt.MapFrom(dest => dest.RequestId));
```

O conteúdo do campo "ArquivoJson" é uma string com um json válido dentro. Eu deserealizo o seu conteúdo no campo "Ligacao". Tenho a maioria dos campos nesse json. Um dos campos que eu não tenho e preciso preencher é o campo "RequestId". Essa informação está no campo de mesmo nome na classe "Ligacao". Como essa informação estão em um "subnível", fiz uma segunda configuração no meu mapeamento. Mas não funciona!

Json:

```
{
   "Fila":10079,
   "Telefone":"1199998888",
   "Nome":"Fulano",
   "Email":"email@email.com",
   "CPF":"999.999.999-99",
   "CodigoCliente":"5",
   "Ordem":null,
   "RequestId":0,
   "CamposAdicionais":[
      {
         "Chave":"veiculo",
         "Valor":"FZO-1710"
      },
      {
         "Chave":"url",
         "Valor":"http://www.google.com.br"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Perceba que o ReuqestId que vem do json está com o valor zero, por isso faço aquele segundo mapeamento para preencher o RequestId, mas ele não altera o valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sua classe deve ser algo como:

```
public class LigacaoGet
{
    public int Fila { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public string Ordem { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public List<LigacaoCamposAdicionais> CamposAdicionais {get;set;}

}

public class LigacaoCamposAdicionais 
{
    public string Chave {get;set;}
    public string Valor {get;set;}
}
```

O `AutoMapper` só utiliza para mapear classes entre classes. O `JSON` não precisa dele. Basta usar o `JsonConvert`

```
string json = "{ \"Fila\":10079, \"Telefone\":\"1199998888\", \"Nome\":\"Fulano\", \"Email\":\"email@email.com\", \"CPF\":\"999.999.999-99\", \"CodigoCliente\":\"5\", \"Ordem\":null, \"RequestId\": 0, \"CamposAdicionais\":[ { \"Chave\":\"veiculo\", \"Valor\":\"FZO-1710\" }, { \"Chave\":\"url\", \"Valor\":\"http://www.google.com.br\" } ] }";

LigacaoGet obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LigacaoGet>(json);
```